# Configure postgresql on ubuntu using a terminal

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu

I installed Postgresql on my virtual machine running ubuntu using the command

`sudo apt-get install postgresql-client`

Next, I need to set up the connection string, login roles, databases, etc... However, I need to do it in the terminal since I don't have a GUI. Does anyone know how to do this or can point on a tutorial on how to do so??

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these command:

[Install and Configure Postgres](http://openies.com/install-openerp-odoo-9-on-ubuntu-server-14-04-lts/)

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

This command will install postgres 9.1 by default in ubuntu 14.04 or any debian distribution. if you want to use any specific version of postgres(i.e 9.3, 9.4) you need to update the source list. for example to install postgres-9.4 you can follow below steps.
Create the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list, and add a line for the repository using vim or nano editor

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main
```

Import the repository signing key, and update the package lists

```
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

and update the packages using

```
sudo apt-get update
```

after that you can search/install the available/supported postgres version

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4
```

After installing postgres 9.4, change to the postgres user so we have the necessary privileges to configure the database

```
sudo su - postgres
```

Now create a new database user with access to create and drop database.

```
createuser --createdb --username postgres --no-createrole --no-superuser --pwprompt odoo

Enter password for new role: ********
Enter it again: ********
```

Finally exit from the postgres user account:

```
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

`man psql` or the official [`psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-psql.html) docs. Also see the [tutorial](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 1):

On the server run the commands below.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

Create a database and a user to access it

I prefer to create one user per database for security.

Replace DATABASE_NAME_HERE and USER_NAME_HERE with the values that you want to use

## this will prompt you for a database password

```
sudo -u postgres createuser -P USER_NAME_HERE
sudo -u postgres createdb -O USER_NAME_HERE DATABASE_NAME_HERE
```

Test connecting to Postgresql

> psql -h localhost -U USER_NAME_HERE DATABASE_NAME_HERE

Postgresql will ask you for your password. Then you should see:

psql (9.3.5)
SSL connection (cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits: 256)
Type "help" for help.

DATABASE_NAME_HERE=>

To exit type:

\q